# Shared Categorical Y Axis on Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried the below but this gives wrong results - the Y labels of subplot 1 get incorrectly overwritten by the Y labels of subplot 2.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ab = {
   'a': ['a','b','a','b'],
   'b': [1,2,3,4]
}
ab = pd.DataFrame(ab)

cd = {
   'c': ['e','e','f','d'],
   'd': [1,2,3,4]
}
cd = pd.DataFrame(cd)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(
   1, 2,
   figsize = (15, 5), 
   sharey = True,
   sharex = True
)
axs[0].scatter(
   ab['b'], 
   ab['a']
)
axs[1].scatter(
   cd['d'],
   cd['c']
)
```

[image]

The correct result should have all the letters - a,b,d,e,f on the Y axis, preferably in order, and the points of the scatter plot placed correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values of `a` and `c` columns are unique, is possible `reindex` by union of both:

```
cats = np.union1d(ab['a'], cd['c'])
ab = ab.set_index('a').reindex(cats)
cd = cd.set_index('c').reindex(cats)
```

and then plot instead columns `index`es:

```
# print(dfFormationSets4.head())
fig, axs = plt.subplots(
   1, 2,
   figsize = (15, 5), 
   sharey = True,
   sharex = True
)
axs[0].scatter(
   ab['b'], 
   ab.index
)
axs[1].scatter(
   cd['d'],
   cd.index
)
```

If not unique values is necessary use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) with [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for add missing categories:

```
ab = {
   'a': ['a','b','a','b'],
   'b': [1,2,3,4]
}
ab = pd.DataFrame(ab)

cd = {
   'c': ['e','e','f','d'],
   'd': [1,2,3,4]
}
cd = pd.DataFrame(cd)
```

---

```
cats = np.union1d(ab['a'], cd['c'])
print (cats)
['a' 'b' 'd' 'e' 'f']

ab1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.setdiff1d(cats, ab['a'].unique())})
ab = ab.append(ab1, ignore_index=True).sort_values('a')
print (ab)
   a    b
0  a  1.0
2  a  3.0
1  b  2.0
3  b  4.0
4  d  NaN
5  e  NaN
6  f  NaN

cd1 = pd.DataFrame({'c': np.setdiff1d(cats, cd['c'].unique())})
cd = cd.append(cd1, ignore_index=True).sort_values('c')
print (cd)
   c    d
4  a  NaN
5  b  NaN
3  d  4.0
0  e  1.0
1  e  2.0
2  f  3.0
```

---

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(
   1, 2,
   figsize = (15, 5), 
   sharey = True,
   sharex = True
)
axs[0].scatter(
   ab['b'], 
   ab['a']
)
axs[1].scatter(
   cd['d'],
   cd['c']
)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Sorry, but they aren't unique. I didn't know that would affect the solution. I'll edit the question.

Comment: This seems to be working but is there no better way without duplicating the data? This would be an issue if I had a really large dataset.

Comment: @TheComeOnMan I have no other idea, but there is no problem if ploting many categoricals? I think many values in axis x should be overlapping?

Comment: I meant from a holding that data in memory rather than the charting.

Answer (score 0):

Because the y-axis categories are not the same, this is happening. I have checked they work if the values of categories ('a' etc.) are same in both dataframes. From the matplotlib [subplot man page](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

> When subplots have a shared x-axis along a column, only the x tick
>   labels of the bottom subplot are created. Similarly, when subplots
>   have a shared y-axis along a row, only the y tick labels of the first
>   column subplot are created.

In this case this is what happening. I am not sure if the categorical values don't match, then what matplotlib can choose as tick labels.

Comment: This may be just about what gets displayed and not actually about how it's plotted?

Answer (score 0):

You could trick the axis to plot numerical values and change the labels manually:

```
# Imports and data

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ab = {
   'a': ['a','b','a','b'],
   'b': [1,2,3,4]
}
ab = pd.DataFrame(ab)

cd = {
   'c': ['e','e','f','d'],
   'd': [1,2,3,4]
}
cd = pd.DataFrame(cd)

# from categorical to numerical
idx = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(np.unique(list(ab['a']) + list(cd['c'])))}

fig, axs = plt.subplots(
   1, 2,
   figsize = (15, 5), 
   sharey = True,
   sharex = True
)

# correct ticks
axs[0].set_yticks(range(len(idx)))
axs[0].set_yticklabels(idx.keys())

axs[0].scatter(
   ab['b'], 
   [idx[i] for i in ab['a']] # plot numerical
)
axs[1].scatter(
   cd['d'],
   [idx[i] for i in cd['c']] # plot numerical
)

plt.show()
```

Resulting Plot:

[image]

Comment: Better to add the result as an image in the answer rather than as a link.

Comment: First post on stackoverflow, I can't yet ;).

Comment: I have added it for you. Once the edit gets approved, you can see it.